# Fetch data from my cloud Firestore and save it to an Object in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

i want to find a way to retrieve my data from my cloud firestore and save it to an object so I can iterate through it, this was my attempt, but I'm sure this might be an array not an object

```
   async function findTrades() {

        const ref1 = admin.firestore().collection("bets");

        const snapshot = await ref1.get();
        const bets = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {

            bets.push(doc.data());

        });

        const tokenIds = await Promise.all(results);

        return console.log("Here =>" + tokenIds);

    }
```

I want to be able to iterate through it like this

```
  bets.forEach(async match => { console.log(bets.id.name)

    });
```

Comment: where matches and results are defined?

Comment: sorry i edited it, i used bets instead, but the previous version was just a hyperthical

Comment: the variable bets only live in  findTrades scope (you don't return it) so where do you want to iterate on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate over an object using a forEach loop. You do need an array for it.

```
async function findTrades() {
    const ref1 = admin.firestore().collection("bets");
    const snapshot = await ref1.get();
    const bets = {};

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        bets[doc.id] = doc.data();
    });

    console.log(bets)
}
```

You can try this code to get something like:

```
{
  "doc1Id": doc1Data,
  "doc2Id": doc2Data
}
```

But as I mentioned above you cannot use a forEach loop on this object. So it's good to have it as an array. Also if you try this code `console.log(typeof bets)` it'll log object even if it's an array.

Just in case you want it as a key-value pair and still use forEach, you can try this:

```
Object.keys(bets).forEach((betId) => {
  console.log(bets[betId]["name"])
})
```

Here `betId` is the document ID and name is just a field in that document.

*PS: You can use a for loop as suggested by @Renaud.*

Answer (score 0):

`doc.data()` retrieves all fields in the `doc` document as an Object: let's call it a "*doc Object*".

Since you are looping on the results of a Query (to the entire `bets` collection), instead of pushing the *doc Objects* to an Array, you could create an object with these *doc Objects*, as follows.

```
const bets = {};
snapshot.forEach(doc => {

   bets[doc.id] = doc.data();

});

// Then you loop on the Object entries
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(bets)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

---

See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) for more ways on looping on an Object entries.

Comment: the console prints this out "qcutL6NW54fhcEobdUw0: [object Object] ", how do I access the nested values?

Comment: You can use the same method to loop over the object entries. `Object.entries(value)`